# Example for type bytes32 in Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I have a function to set nickname:

```
function setNickname(bytes32 _nickname) public payable {
    lords[msg.sender].lordAddr = msg.sender;
    lords[msg.sender].nickname = _nickname;
    emit SetNickname(msg.sender, _nickname);
}
```

Then, I have deployed in Remix IDE and run function `setNickname` with input "Name one". But I received this response from Remix:

```
Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid bytes32 value
```

What is the correct input?

Comment: It should be `0x` followed by a 64-character hexadecimal string. E.g. `0x7465737400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (corresponding to the ASCII string `"test"`).

Answer (score 2):

For convert a `string` to `bytes32` you can use this [tool](https://web3-type-converter.onbrn.com/). You put string into the first textbox, choose `bytes32/hex` type from dropdown and then you must to copy the result generated in the second textbox.
Now, you add '0' until you have the length of this bytes32 is equal to 64 (this because bytes takes up 2 slot of memory) without counting the '0x' characters. At this point, you can put this new value into it your bytes32 input parameters function.

Example:

string = *blue*

bytes32 = *0x626c756500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*

Answer (score 0):

Function expects you to pass bytes32 value but instead you are passing a string.
This link can be useful in converting for the same
https://web3-type-converter.onbrn.com/ and try passing bytes32 value.

Comment: Hello. Please avoid link only answer. Your link may be unavailable in the future. instead, write a full answer with a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If the tool in the link above is not working, one way to do this is to add this function to Remix

```
pragma solidity 0.8.15;

contract StringToBytesConverter {
    function stringToBytes(string calldata str) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return abi.encodePacked(str);
    }
}
```

It will output the string in bytes array then you can add the remaining zeros so it is a 64-character hexadecimal string.